# Alter table, add 2 new columns : 1 column a calculation of the other newly added?

Tags: sql

Given the table Units_table:

```
Units
5
34
365
34
```

Write a query that produces the output below:

| Units | KWh | MWh |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 67.5 | 0.0675 |
| 34 | 459 | 0.459 |
| 365 | 4927.5 | 4.9275 |
| 34 | 459 | 0.459 |

So far, here is what I have:

```
SELECT * FROM Units_table
ALTER TABLE Units_table
ADD KWh, int
ADD MWh, int
INSERT INTO Units_table (KWh, MWh)
VALUES (67.5, 0.0675), (459, 0.459), (4927.5,  4.9275), (459, 0.459)
SELECT * FROM Units_table;
```

Problem is I feel this is inefficient due to the data values I entered. How can I streamline the code to divide KWh by 1000 and produce the MWh value?

Comment: What is the relationship between units, KWh and MWh?

Comment: Is it SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL server:

```
Alter table yourtable add MWh as (kWh/1000);
```

You might need to cast kWh to a decimal or similar type if you want to see fractional digits.

Comment: Sweet, updated to …SELECT * FROM Units_table
ALTER TABLE Units_table ADD KWh int NOT NULL, 
ALTER TABLE Units_table ADD MWh as KWh/1000
INSERT INTO Units_table, KWh
VALUES (67.5, 459, 4927.5, 459)
SELECT * FROM Units_table

Answer (score 0):

Use a [*view*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)):

```
create view units_view as
select
  Units,
  KWh,
  KWh / 1000 as MWh
from units_table
```

Treat it as a table in all respects, except that you would not be able to directly update the `MWh` column because it's a calculated value, but its value will change if `KWh` is updated. Or just direct inserts and updates to `units_table` and use the view for selects.